# Localization Windows Store App MakePRI warning

Tags: windows-8

I have added localized strings for my app as Resources.resw files under corresponding folders (en-US, nb-NO) and get the following warning when compiling:

**MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid Qualifier: EN-US**

**MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid Qualifier: NB-NO**

I suspect invalid characters as keys but I am unable to track down the offenders.

Here is the build output:

```
1>Task "GenerateProjectPriFile"
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\MakePri.exe New -ProjectRoot "C:\Users\Eivind\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FructoseStore\FructoseStore\\" -ConfigXml obj\Debug\priconfig.xml -OutputFile "C:\Users\Eivind\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FructoseStore\FructoseStore\bin\Debug\resources.pri" -IndexName 1e111781-63c0-4629-81a6-442da5904cb6 -Verbose -Overwrite  
1>  Option Verbose specified
1>  Option Overwrite specified
1>  Index Pass Completed: obj\Debug\layout.resfiles
1>  
1>  Index Pass Completed: obj\Debug\resources.resfiles
1>  Language Qualifiers: EN-US, NB-NO
1>  
1>  Index Pass Completed: obj\Debug\pri.resfiles
1>  Language Qualifiers: EN-US, NB-NO
1>  
1>  Finished building
1>  Version: 1.0
1>  Resource Map Name: 1e111781-63c0-4629-81a6-442da5904cb6
1>  Named Resources: 79
1>  Resource Candidates: 140
1>  Output File at C:\Users\Eivind\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FructoseStore\FructoseStore\bin\Debug\resources.pri
1>  Successfully Completed
1>MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid Qualifier: EN-US
1>MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid Qualifier: NB-NO
1>Done executing task "GenerateProjectPriFile".
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can gather this was resolved by restarting Visual Studio.